# Force Jenkins to reinstall JDK made available through Global Tool Configuration

Tags: jenkins

I recently made available Amazon Corretto 11.0.12.7.1 with the name `OpenJDK11Latest` on the Jenkins Global Tool Configuration Page auto installed with extract `.zip/.tar.gz`

My requirements changed and I now have to use Oracle's 11.0.2 version instead. However, when I swapped the image the build still failed due to the Amazon Corretto version still existing in the `OpenJDK11Latest` directory (the extracted subdirectory is named differently for the different versions).

I am able to fix this by creating a new JDK that is named differently, but this is very suboptimal as I have to then change where it is used in my pipeline definitions (around 8 places).

How can I force the re-download of this JDK in my builds. I have future concerns in case we want to upgrade the version again or we do actually end up replacing it in the end.

Comment: Have you looked at `JENKINS_HOME/.jenkins/tools/...`? Either replace the installation there or I can imagine that removing the installation/renaming the dir causes Jenkins to install it once again from the source.

Comment: On master? @GeroldBroser

Comment: Yes. And I made a mistake. It's not JENKINS_HOME, it's JENKINS_DATA. Can just tell it for Windows atm, e.g for Maven: `C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven_3.8.1`.

Comment: Another less hacky idea: What if you _Delete Installer_ → _Apply_ (in G.T.C.) and _Add Installer_ with the same name but different source? Your pipelines' `Jenkinsfile`s aren't influenced by that.

Comment: Shoot, should’ve added that as something I did which failed